# Weird question but why is my Form submitting when I did not click on the button

Tags: php, html, arrays, function

The code below is a plus and minus button that is suppose to add 1 or minus 1 from the quantity of my shopping cart.

```
<form method="post" style="margin: 0; display: inline-block;">
      <button method="submit" name="plusBtn" value="add">+</button>
      <button method="submit" name="minusBtn" value="minus">-</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="productID" value="<?php echo $array['shoeId']; ?>">
</form>
```

This is the function to add or minus 1

```
        function plusQuantity(){
            $productId = $_POST['productID'];
            foreach($_SESSION['finalCart'] as $eachItem){
                if($eachItem['shoeId'] === $productId){
                        $eachItem['quantity']+1;
                }
            }
        }
        function minusQuantity(){
            $productId = $_POST['productID'];
            foreach($_SESSION['finalCart'] as $eachItem){
                if($eachItem['shoeId'] === $productId){
                    if($eachItem['quantity'] = 1){
                        unset($eachItem['shoeId']);
                    } else {
                        $eachItem['quantity']-1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I am calling the functions

```
        if(isset($_POST['plusBtn'])){
            plusQuantity();
            print_r($_SESSION['finalCart']);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['minusBtn'])){
            minusQuantity();
        }
```

However the function sort of just load by itself when the page loads and the function doesn't seem to be working also however I added like the print_r($_SESSION['finalCart'] or even some echo texts to the calling of the function part to see if the function is running and indeed it was running by itself. Would be grateful for any help I can get still new to php and trying to learn it Thanks.

Comment: `<button method="submit"` – what is that supposed to be? `button` does not have a `method` attribute. It has `formmethod` - but that would have to be used with an actually valid form submission method, `submit` is not one.

Comment: _“However the function sort of just load by itself when the page loads and the function doesn't seem to be working also however”_ - really unclear what you even mean by that. Please _properly_ explain what happens when you load the page, and how that differs from what you would have expected.

Comment: _“This is the function to add or minus 1”_ - _assigning_ a fixed value of 20 is not really “adding one” either …

Comment: If you dump your post data, var_dump(post) you can see that you are not sending any plusBtn or minusBtn parameter. Your option id create two forms. One for minus and one for plus. Sending your parameters like the product id

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the button method, I meant to put type but I guess I didn't check again.

Comment: I amended the change for the button to type=submit and that solved the function running by itself. 

So it would seem my function is wrong. But I will try to look into it later thank you! @04FS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way of doing this is to use Ajax calls which would fire of JavaScript calls and get the response back without having to reload the page on submit.

Or, you could make (very ugly solution) make two forms:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="plusBtn" value="add">
  <input type="submit" value="+">
</form>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="plusBtn" value="minus">
  <input type="submit" value="-">
</form>
```

But I would rather style Radio buttons etc or something and use a proper Ajax call.

Comment: Ouups the name on the second one should be "minusBtn"